# Find the antiderivatives

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the antiderivatives:

$\int\!\left(2x^2 +3\right)^{1/3} x\,dx $

I have hit this in my book and the way I do it I get

$3/4\left(2x^2 + 3\right)^{4/3} x^2 +c $

But my book tells me it should be $3/16(2x^2 + 3)^{4/3}$

Anyone know how they get to that?

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitution $u=x^2+3$. Then $du=4x\,dx$ so $x\,dx=\frac{1}{4}\,du$.
Thus
$$\int (2x^2+3)^{1/3} x\,dx=\int \frac{1}{4}u^{1/3}\,du.$$

**Remark:** The derivative of $2x^2+3$ is "almost" part of your expression. sure, we have an $x$ instead of $4x$, but that's no problem, since $x=\frac{1}{4}(4x)$. In this kind of situation, substitution is often useful. You will meet variants often, like $\int xe^{x^2}\,dx$, or $\int (1+\sin x)^8\cos x\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $u=2x^2+3, du=4x$.    It is unfortunately not true that $\int f(x) g(x)dx=\int f(x)dx \int g(x)dx$; you cannot integrate the $x$ part separately.